# Translation of System UI Buttons

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use translation via **LocalicationResourceManager** and the corresponding culture is set like this:

```cs
CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(value.Key);

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;

// Set the culture for localization
LocalizationResourceManager.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
LanguageResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(newCulture);
```

I also use the following section in the **Info.plist**:

```xml
...
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>de</string>
</array>
...
```

Additionally, I added a key/value in my AppResources.de.resx with a Translation for "Done".

I also tried the translation part within an EntryKeyboardHandler for the "Done"-Button:

```cs
#if IOS

using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using System.Drawing;
using UIKit;

namespace MyApp;

public class EntryKeyboardHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler
{
    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiTextField platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        // Create a new toolbar.
        var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

        // Create a new UIBarButton with a delegate to clear the focus on the Entry by calling a method that forces the text to stop being edited.
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
        {
            this.PlatformView.EndEditing(true);
        });

        // Add the button to the toolbar previosly created
        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[]
        {
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            doneButton
        };

        this.PlatformView.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
}

#endif
```

Unfortunately, none of my system "Done"-Buttons and what is also available from the System itself are translated. What I wanted to achieve is that when I switch my Language for the App internally, also all System-Buttons like "Done" for a "Picker" etc. should also be translated.

Do I really have to implement own Handlers for each an every Button that comes from the System to internally switch my Language independent from actually is the OS Language?
Also my question right now is if I really have to implement this platform specific Code also for other parts that are Android-/iOS-specific (like "Cancel"-Buttons for Alerts etc.) or are there Options, which I missed above and could try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Localize text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/localization?view=net-maui-8.0#localize-text). Localized text can be retrieved by using the x:Static markup extension to access the generated static properties:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:LocalizationDemo.Resources.Strings">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="{x:Static strings:AppResources.AddButton}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I more or less was talking about System Buttons like "Done" when opening a Picker for instance. I did not want to customize each and every control by myself. For the Picker, I also added a PickerHandler for that. But, I was asking myself if there is a general property or something I have to set besides the CultureInfo (which did not have an effect on the Picker) and which easily switches the System Default Buttons.